# How do I know the ID's of views if I am inflating a view multiple times in the same parent on button click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a difficult situation, let me put it this way, I want the user to use my 3 text-fields to set data for alarm and after filling in the information, I give him an option to set another alarm for this purpose I use a button. I have three table rows in a table layout which are defined in a child.xml file and every element has an Id set. In my activity, I inflate child.xml multiple times on button click event and I am able to successfully inflate it as many times as I want. But my problem is since I am inflating the same xml file many times(I don't know how many times) at runtime, I am confused as of how would I retrieve the data from particular text-fields like TextViews and identify them by a unique IDs since I am required to do so.
How do you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will start from basic

```
<Layout>
<Button1>
</layout>
```

Now in activity

```
Button btn;View view1=null;
///Inflate file if view is null
first time when you inflating
view1=inflate
 btn=view1.findViewbyid();
```

Now suppose you have inflate another view but view1 value is not changed then btn willl contain reference for that button.And when it became visible.It will work as like normal button.

Comment: No I am still confused 
I get it, we can count the number of elements by using List, but I wanted to know as of how to get the data from TextViews, suppose I inflate 10 table layouts then how do I collect data from all of them? The main thing Iam confused of is that how will I be able to distinguish between them when I know that they all share the same ID

Comment: you can set id using an integer and increment every time to recognize each element differently.

Comment: I have their Id's defined in the xml file. I want to access those fields after dynamically inflating view.

Comment: Please have a look at my implementation
for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
      tv1=(TextView)l.get(i).findViewById(R.id.mdsnew_type_sp);
      tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
     
    }
   });

Comment: the problem is the onclicklistener is only being set for the first view that is inflated, I want it to be implemented on all possible textviews.

Comment: oh ...then take one array of button tv1[];and set onclickListener() by taking for loop and setOnclicklitener like tv1[i].setOnclicklistener(this).and check for the i value and pop appropriate dialog

Comment: public void getData(){
     TextView[] tv=new TextView[l.size()];
     for(int i=0;i<tv.length;i++){
   
   
   tv[i]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mdsnew_type_sp);
   tv[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      
      showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
     
    }
   });

Comment: Please have a look at the above code, I still dont get a dialog when I click on textview corresponding to sencond inflated layout.

Answer (score 2):

I would go programmatically about it.

When the user requests for a new alarm, then you inflate your xml file. At this point, **keep a reference to the inflated view** (in a List, or some other sort of collection) in your activity.

So when you want to retrieve the data, don't use `findViewById`, just use your reference instead.

Comment: I use the following code to inflate it, how do I keep a reference?

myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelyt1);
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater, myRoot);

Comment: this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater, myRoot);, or better, add it to a this.viewList (which is a List<View>)

Comment: I get it, we can count the number of elements by using List, but I wanted to know as of how to get the data from TextViews, suppose I inflate 10 table layouts then how do I collect data from all of them? The main thing Iam confused of is that how will I be able to distinguish between them when I know that they all share the same ID

Comment: When you need to use one, retrieve it from the list, and NOT using its  id from the activity. If that's not clear to you, then you need to provide additional details on your question of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean to say that after adding the view to the list it now contains references to all the UI elements within the view? I want to collect data from all the textviews from all inflated views and populate it in a different textview. Please have a look at my implementn

 public void getData(){
     for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
      tv1=(TextView)l.get(i).findViewById(R.id.mdsnew_type_sp);
      tv2=(TextView)l.get(i).findViewById(R.id.mdsnew_type_sp2);  
     }
     System.out.println(tv1.getText().toString());
  System.out.println(tv2.getText().toString());
  System.out.println(l.size());

Answer (score 2):

may be this can help...

---

```
            LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.i1);   ///main xml file which contains the layout i m inflating
            String str[]={"a","b","c"};
            View vi[]=new View[3];
            LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                  View v=li.inflate(R.layout.addit, null);
                  TextView t=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.t1);
                  t.setText(str[i]);
                  ll.addView(v);
                      vi[i]=v;
            }
            TextView t1=new TextView(this);
            TextView t2=new TextView(this);
            TextView t3=new TextView(this);
            TextView r1=(TextView) vi[0].findViewById(R.id.t1);
            TextView r2=(TextView) vi[1].findViewById(R.id.t1);
            TextView r3=(TextView) vi[2].findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t1.setText(r1.getText());
            t2.setText(r2.getText());
            t3.setText(r3.getText());
            ll.addView(t1);
            ll.addView(t2);
            ll.addView(t3);

             setContentView(ll);
```

my addit.xml file contains the following :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/l2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/t1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:text="" />
       </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>
```

here i m adding dynamically the layout from addit.xml 3 times which contains the textview with id t1..
for each textview i m setting a text from the string array str ..
and adding each view object v to an array for referencing ...
now if i want to get the text for each textview i can use the reference to the view stored in the array and  find the text view by id as in the code to get the text from each textview

[image]

Comment: earlier i was trying to do this on edittext when the snapshot was taken  but later decided to do it on textview ,so the edittext box are visible in the pic ...

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the `View` reference you get back when you `inflate()` each instance. Cast these to `TextView` when you need to read text from them.

Comment: I inflate it like this

myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelyt1);
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater, myRoot);

Comment: You need to store the View returned from inflater.inflate(). At the moment you are ignoring the return value.